# How to use Semantic UI in Angular 8

Tags: angular

I've done npm install semantic-ui-css, jquery and @types/jquery. After that I runned the app and changed the package.json file to reference the jquery and semantic ui files. The app reloaded and the magic showed, Semantic UI worked. But after I stopped the app and runned it again. It complains about the jquery sysntax on the component. $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown({})

Cannot find name $

So I add

import * as $ from 'jquery'

but it cannot find the semantic ui code. It complains about the function dropdown, it doesn't exit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get over it by adding this ($('ui.dropdown')).dropdown();